# add_post_meta insert null value into Database

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

l try this code :

```
add_post_meta($post_id, 'province', esc_attr($_POST['postProvince']), true);
```

checked :
    esc_attr($_POST['postProvince']

> And it Contains Value

But add_post_meta insert null in database

it Happened only to **province** And **city** keys, other parameters insert into database correctly.

found problem area.

there is a plugin add this data to post (**add_post_meta**) and show into wp-admin Dashboard , method called by :

```
add_action( 'added_post_meta', 'ipc_add_to_post_meta', 10, 4 );
```

in plugin

when i try to use **add_post_meta** or **update_post_meta** insert null

wp version : **4.9.4**

--------------- Update

problem is can not pass parameters using `$_REQUEST` And `$_POST`

Comment: Please include the whole block of code, to further diagnose the issues.

Comment: What values does your DB table configuration allow in the `province` column?

Comment: i did not changed configuration i think it is nvar_char

Answer (score -1):

Try **update_post_meta** function without **esc_attr**

```
<?php 
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'province', $_POST['postProvince'], true);
?>
```

Comment: You should never save user input directly into the database without sanitization. Use `sanitze_text_field()`, not `esc_attr()`.

Comment: Post updated. Please check it out

Comment: why would this make any difference?